# JAX-RS Mudar nome do Conjunto

Tags: java, web-service, jax-rs

Eu criei um projeto usando JAX-RS para fazer um web service REST e ele funciona, consigo acessar o resultado em um recurso e tudo mais mas ele vem assim:

```
{
  "carroes": {
    "carro": [
      {
        "@id": "1",
        "modelo": "Gol",
        "marca": "VW",
        "ano": 1995
      },
      {
        "@id": "2",
        "modelo": "Golf",
        "marca": "VW",
        "ano": 2010
      },
      {
        "@id": "3",
        "modelo": "Brasilia",
        "marca": "VW",
        "ano": 1984
      },
      {
        "@id": "4",
        "modelo": "Passat Variant",
        "marca": "VW",
        "ano": 1979
      },
      {
        "@id": "5",
        "modelo": "Passat",
        "marca": "VW",
        "ano": 1978
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

O problema é o nome do conjunto, `carroes`, deveria ser `carros`.

O estranho é que não configurei `carroes` em lugar algum, pelo menos não me lembro de ter colocado esse nome em nenhum lugar.
Alguém sabe aonde posso mudar esse nome?

Olha como esta meu Serviço:

```
@Path("/carros")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML + ";charset=UTF-8"})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML + ";charset=UTF-8"})
public class CarroService {

    private static CarroDAO carroDao = new CarroDAO();

    @GET        
    public List<Carro> listarCarros(){      
        List<Carro> carrosList = carroDao.findAll();    
        return carrosList;
    }


    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    public Carro buscaCarroID(@PathParam("id") int id){
        Carro carro = carroDao.findById(id);

        return carro;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/modelo/{nome}")
    public List<Carro> findCarrosForName(@PathParam("nome") String nome){
        List<Carro> carros = carroDao.findCarrosForName(nome);
        return carros;
    }


    @DELETE
    @Path("{id}")
    public ResponseBuilder deletarCarro(@PathParam("id") int id){
        carroDao.delete(id);

        return Response.ok("Carro Excluido");
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

o atributo carroes provavelmente esta vindo do seu modelo "Carro", quando o JAX-RS converte (serializa) para JSON ele por padrão utiliza o mesmo nome de seus atributos.